# Target images inside slider

Tags: jquery

I have made a custom slider.. with a bit of help.. I need some help targeting images when clicking the next button.

my codepen is here
https://codepen.io/erayner/pen/LLBwOj

essentially when I click the next button i just want to hide one of the images.

```
//example of one of the slides
<div class="row slide slide2">
        <div class="col-sm-6 slide2-container">
            <div class="slide2-container1">
                <h4>Burglar</h4>
                <p>A burglar looks for an easy entry point</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Unlocked doors</li>
                    <li>Open windows</li>
                </ul>
                <p>To keep burglars out, effective security should</p>
                <p><span>Discover</span> them on the edge of your property before they get in.</p>
                <p><span>Enforce</span> existing security measures to maintain high security standards.</p>
                <p><span>Harden</span> security tools to make entry difficult.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slide2-container2">
                <h4>Cyber Hacker</h4>
                <p>Cyber attackers look for easy entry points</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Social engineering/phishing to get an unsuspecting user to expose their network credentials or install malware</li>
                    <li>Exploiting a vulnerability in a web-based application or service</li>
                </ul>
                <p>To keep attackers out, effective security should</p>
                <p><span>Discover</span> when malicious sites, applications or downloads are being accessed.</p>
                <p><span>Enforce</span> existing security measures to block this activity.</p>
                <p><span>Harden</span> security tools to make entry difficult before a connection is established.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 slide2">
            <img src="http://ciscosecurity.co.nz/test-images/state-2.svg" class="svg svg1">
            <img src="http://ciscosecurity.co.nz/test-images/state-1.svg" class="svg">
        </div>
    </div>

//jquery im trying to get to hide '.active .svg(1,2,3)'
jQuery('.arrow-left, .arrow-right').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.active').hasClass('slide2')) {
        $('.svg2').hide();
    } else {
        $('.svg2').show();
    }
    t($(this));
});
```

any help greatly appreciated.
Cheers

EDIT: Updated jQuery -> 'previous' button doesn't work with code but 'next' does

Comment: Could you please copy all the relevant code from Codepen into your question? See [mcve] for what to include. Thanks!

Comment: Updated, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just a matter of targeting the correct element here is an example that I think is trying to do what you want.

https://codepen.io/natedog213/pen/RgJZYd?editors=1111

```
if ($('.slide2').hasClass('current')){
   $('.slide2').children().last().css('top', '-300px');
}else{
   $('.slide2').children().last().css('top' , '100px');
}
```